# Asterisk Triangle

Tags: python

I'm coming from a background in Google's App Inventor. I'm taking an online class.

Task: Make a triangle out of asterisks with a nested while loop. The triangle has a base of 19 asterisks and a height of 10 asterisks.

Here's where I am.

```
Num = 1

while Num <= 19:

        print '*'
        Num = Num * '*' + 2
print Num
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the 'center'-method from string-objects:

```
width = 19

for num in range(1, width + 1, 2):
     print(('*' * num).center(width))

         *         
        ***        
       *****       
      *******      
     *********     
    ***********    
   *************   
  ***************  
 ***************** 
*******************
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing with
    Num = Num * '*' + 2
is the following:

- you create a string (Num-times '*') this is what you want
- then you try to add two, you'll probably see an error like *cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects*, because there is no way to add a *string* to an *int* (at least in python). Instead you probably want to add two only to *Num*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cool trick - in Python, you can multiply a string by a number with `*`, and it will become that many copies of the string concatenated together.

```
>>> "X "*10
'X X X X X X X X X X '
```

And you can concatenate two strings together with `+`:

```
>>> " "*3 + "X "*10
'   X X X X X X X X X X '
```

So your Python code can be a simple for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    s = ""
    # concatenate to s how many spaces to align the left side of the pyramid?
    # concatenate to s how many asterisks separated by spaces?
    print s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 0
w = 19
h = 10
rows = []
while n < h:
    rows.append(' '*n+'*'*(w-2*n)+' '*n)
    n += 1
print('\n'.join(reversed(rows)))
```

Produces

```
         *         
        ***        
       *****       
      *******      
     *********     
    ***********    
   *************    #etc...
  ***************   #2 space on both sides withd-4 *
 *****************  #1 space on both sides, width-2 *
******************* #0 spaces
>>> len(rows[-1])
19
>>> len(rows)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you wouldn't use a nested while loop for this problem, but here's one way

```
rows = 10
while rows:
    rows -=1
    cols = 20
    line = ""
    while cols:
        cols -=1
        if rows < cols < 20-rows:
            line += '*'
        else:
            line += ' '
    print line
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This makes sense to me logically...but my only issue is now figuring out how to make this look the same as the example here: https://sites.google.com/site/colinclaytonappinventor/python-work (I couldn't post the image of the pyramid any other way due to me being a new member)  How would I flip it over?

Answer (score 0):

`(count - 1) * 2 + 1` calculates the number of asterisks in each row.

```
count = 1
while count <= 10:
    print('*' * ((count - 1) * 2 + 1))
    count += 1
```

You can go the easy way of course.

```
count = 1
while count <= 20:
    print('*' * count)
    count += 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This also seems very easy for me to comprehend, but I need to find a way to adjust it to look more like the photo example here https://sites.google.com/site/colinclaytonappinventor/python-work I guess this is where I would use the nested while loop, but I'm confused at what I would be adjusting. The transition from a block language like app inventor to python has been a little challenging...